# swift Range init function error

Tags: swift

My code

```
self.p_formatterTime = self.pubTime?.substringWithRange(Range<Int>(start: 5, end: 11))
```

Compile Error Message：

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Range<Int>' with an argument list of type '(start: Int, end: Int)'
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if let a = self.pubTime {
    self.p_formatterTime = a.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: a.startIndex.advancedBy(5), end: a.startIndex.advancedBy(11)))
    // ...
}
```

And an working example, since I don' really know if your strings `self.p_formatterTime` and `self.pubTime?` are even valid strings:

```
let myString = "0123456789ABCDEFG"
let mySubString = myString.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: myString.startIndex.advancedBy(5), end: myString.startIndex.advancedBy(11)))
print(mySubString) // prints "56789A"
```